# How to deploy a custom build of a Jenkins core plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to deploy a custom build of a core plugin bundled in Jenkins?

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy a custom field"? If you've customized/forked a core plugin, you can probably just plop the hpi file in there and override the built-in one (disclaimer: haven't tried this, but worth looking in to).

Comment: @AssafLavie edited the question to properly ask about `build`, not `field`.

Comment: Please demonstrate more research into the question. Especially since we are still in private beta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This section](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-Deployingacustombuildofacoreplugin) of the official [Jenkins Plugin Tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) will probably be of use.

According to the writers of that documentation, you need to copy your .hpi file to `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins`, remove the plugin's development directory, and finally create an empty file called .hpi.pinned for maven to use. Then you should be ready to restart Jenkins and use your custom build of a core plugin.

They also suggest running `mvn clean` when you're ready to update Jenkins to remove old files (after changing core plugins, old .jar files might still be around after updating).